# Consulta MYSQL muito lenta, mais de 25 segundos, como melhorar?

Tags: mysql, select

Tenho uma consulta no mysql que está muito lenta , mais de 25 segundos.

A base é bem grande, algo em torno de 1.000 registros de imoveis (tabela osrs_properties) e 16.000 registros de fotos (tabela osrs_photos).

A consulta sem a foto leva meio segundo, mas com foto leva 25, como posso melhorar a consulta ou a tabela para aumentar a velocidade da consulta?

Abaixo a consulta:

```
SELECT p.ref,p.pro_name, p.id, p.pro_alias, p.precovenda, f.image as fotoimg, MIN(f.ordering) AS foto, p.city, p.bed_room, p.rooms, p.parking, p.square_feet
FROM osrs_properties p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM osrs_photos  ORDER BY ordering ASC) f ON f.pro_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT category_id, pid FROM osrs_property_categories) c ON c.pid = p.id
WHERE p.id > 0
GROUP BY p.pro_name, p.id
ORDER BY p.pro_name, foto DESC
LIMIT 21
```

A consulta `LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM osrs_photos  ORDER BY ordering ASC) f ON f.pro_id = p.id` serve para eu pegar a foto com o menor ordering, ela que está deixando a consulta lenta

Comment: Tenta trocar o `SELECT * FROM osrs_photos` por uma consulta que retorne apenas as colunas que você utilize na sua consulta. Veja se teve algum ganho.

Comment: 1000 registros é praticamente insignificante. O seu problema com certeza são os arquivos de imagem no bd. O ideal é não tê-las no bd, e sim fora, controlando somente o endereço pelo banco. Provavelmente 1 imagem, vale os 1000 registros da sua outra tabelas! rs

Comment: @rbz Não seria uma opção ele guardar no banco porém de uma forma compactada?

Comment: @rbz é então, é que a consulta funciona assim, ele vai trazer todos os imoveis e 1 foto, e essa foto tem que ser a menor (a coluna ordering tem que ser a menor) fiz um teste usando ordering =1, daí vai super rapido, o problema é que tem registros que não tem ordering 1, o menor é 2 por exemplo

Comment: @VictorLaio O problema não é espaço, e sim processamento. Compactar provavelmente irá piorar, pois o banco terá mais 1 passo para abrir a imagem.

Comment: @VictorLaio como asism compactada? (trabalho ha pouco tmepo com mysql)

Comment: @rbz O processo de descompactação seria feito pelo backend pra nao sobrecarregar o banco, e já vi vários processos que podem diminuir o tamanho de uma imagem drásticamente. Nas empresas que eu trabalhei nunca recomendaram o armazenamento no servidor devido a segurança.

Comment: @Leandro, seria compactar a imagem ou usar processos no backend pra diminuir o tamanho da mesma antes de salvar no banco de dados pra não consumir tanto recurso. Tipo o que o WhatsApp faz com as imagens.

Comment: @VictorLaio pelo que entendi, vc disse para dimunuir o tamanho da imagem, isso? se for, não é necessario, o que esta demorando na verdade, é para encontrar a referencia dessa imagem no banco

Comment: @VictorLaio por que você não faz a pesquisa sem a imagem e depois que retornar vai no banco de novo (_async_) pra carregar a imagem? Acho que seja uma solução bem simples e deva resolver o problema

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo Você tentou usar um `SELECT TOP`, e buscar o primeiro registro encontrado, fazendo um `ORDER BY` por outro campo, já que você tem campo `NULL` em `ORDERING`? Esse join provavelmente está causando a lentidão `LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM osrs_photos  ORDER BY ordering ASC) f ON f.pro_id = p.id`

Comment: @rbz aproveitando seu comentário que 1000 registros é insignificante, a partir de qts registros mais ou menos, considero como grande (considerando uma tabela de 5 colunas)

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo Depende muito do seu servidor, do seu banco, dos índices, etc. Mas "basicamente" uma tabela somente com 5 colunas (varchar, int, pensando nos mais utilizados), pode colocar milhões e milhões! rs

Comment: show, obrigado pelos ensinamentos...rs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ja tentou assim:

```
SELECT p.ref, p.pro_name, p.id, p.pro_alias, p.precovenda, f.image as fotoimg, 
MIN(f.ordering) AS foto, p.city, p.bed_room, p.rooms, p.parking, p.square_feet
FROM osrs_properties p
LEFT JOIN osrs_photos f ON f.pro_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN osrs_property_categories c ON c.pid = p.id
WHERE p.id > 0
GROUP BY p.pro_name, p.id
ORDER BY p.pro_name, foto DESC
LIMIT 21
```

Todas as tuas subqueries fazem um tablescan nas tabelas osrs_photos e osrs_property_category.
Tenta da forma que mostrei pra ver se melhora seu desempenho.

Espero ter ajudado. :D

Comment: Show, deu certo sim, levou menos de meio segundo, só pra eu entender, o que exatamente fez? Obrigado!

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo ele eliminou todas as subqueries que estava utilizando nos joins. Como a tabela já tem referência, você pode usar direto. Essas subqueries seriam necessárias ou por falta de referência, ou algo específico. Mas ainda o ideal não é armazenar imagens em bd. Procure aqui no SOpt que tem bastante sobre o assunto.

Comment: @rbz, valeu, é como se minha consulta fossem 3 consultas em uma e esse agora é uma só, isso? Valew!

Comment: A diferença é que você colocando só a tabela, ele só irá fazer a referência direta. Se você coloca uma query, ele executa ela primeiro, depois faz a referência.